# Remotely use a platform device

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers, virtual-machine, hardware

I have a linux/android device with a certain hardware module (lets call this pc A), and a driver which uses the hardware as a platform device.

Because of testing/os restrictions I'd like to be able to "forward" the device from A to another linux machine (B), so that the drivers are loaded on B and all requests/responses to the hardware are transparently moved back and forth between the machines.

Effectively I'd like to use the driver as-is on B, while the virtualization is managed by some lower layer between A and B.

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: if your device is on the usb bus you can use the `usbip` package.

Comment: unfortunately it's not a usb device, but I'm looking for something like that